# RTools packages compilation options

Tags: r, compilation, package

I have a package to install which hardly using computations (block written on fortran and c). So, I want to enable max optimization like mtune=native and other.
2 questions.

1) Where could I find and change base compilation options for g++/gcc?

2) What are best options for maximum code optimization for Corei7-6700K?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Read the documents on [Using `Makevars'](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_11.html).**

- Example

Create the file Makevars or Makevars.win in the folder src, and add your option, 
such as `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -O2 -mtune=native -pipe`.